# Mutt: Save message to different folder but stay on it

Tags: mutt, macro

I'd like to write a macro (index, pager) that saves a message to the `Archive` mailbox but keep the current message open / selected, or even to to the previous entry.

My current macro:

```
macro index,pager a "<save-message>=Archive<enter><previous-entry><enter>" Archive
```

The problem is that `<save-message>` seems to jump to the next entry that is not deleted on its own, so calling `<previous-entry>` does not really do the trick afterwards.

Is there a way of staying at the current message or going to the previous entry after saving a message in a macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attention! It disables the confirmation dialog temporarily.

```
macro index,pager a ":set confirmappend=no<enter><tag-prefix><copy-message>=Archive<enter><sync-mailbox>:set confirmappend=yes<enter>" Archive
```